# What does 'this' mean inside javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I am calling the following 3rd party JavaScript function:

```
var Socket = function(url) {
    sockets.push(this);
    var me = this;
    me.readyState = 0;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        me.readyState = 1;
        me.onopen();
    }, 500);
};
```

via this:

```
connection = new Socket(socketURL);
```

Now I want to try and understand once and for all what it means to reference `this` inside a function.  Is it the same as in Java. e.g. I am referring to myself or in the case of JavaScript I am referring to the namespace that the function resides in?

Comment: In that particular case `this` refers to the newly-created object.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript "this" keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Answer (score 3):

The referece of `this` depends on how you are calling the function.

For example:

```
function globalFn() { return this.val; }

var objectA = { val: 1, localFn: globalFn };
var objectB = { val: 2, localFn: globalFn };

objectA.localFn(); // `this` will be `objectA`, so it returns `1`.
objectB.localFn(); // `this` will be `objectB`, so it returns `2`.
```

So far, so good. It looks like the same as in Java or other object oriented languages. But, this may seem tricky:

```
var myFn = objectA.localFn;
myFn(); // `this` will be `undefined` in strict mode, causing an error
```

This shows that `this` reference is not bound to the function itself, but to the way the function is called. You can "cheat" it by using `call` method of a function object:

```
myFn.call(objectA); // `this` will be `objectA`, returns `1`.
globalFn.call(objectB); // `this` will be `objectB`, returns `2`.
objectA.localFn.call(objectB); // `this` will be `objectB`, returns `2`.
```

You can even do this for objects that does not have the function defined as a property:

```
var objectC = {val: 3};
myFn.call(objectC); // `this` will be `objectC` and will return `3`.
```

It's quite hard to understand it at first, there's a great video that illustrates how it works at YouTube: [The Definitive Guide to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMfcsYzj-9M) by James Shore.

Answer (score 0):

Edited. Previous answer was not correct.  Here's a good explanation:

[code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/fully-understanding-the-codethiscode-keyword--net-21117](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/fully-understanding-the-codethiscode-keyword--net-21117)